# can't figure out how to show latest comment on submit without refreashing the page

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, comments

i am trying to make a post and comment script.Just for learning purpose.What i have done so far is:

## post a status by clicking a submit button

(it will insert the post to a database and  retrieve it from the database to show )

## there will be a comment section for each post,it will take users comment and upload it to database ( problem lies here).

my main problem is i can't manage to show the most recent comment posted when user click the post button. it will be inserted to database when user click the post button but can't show it to them when updated.How can i do that. i need suggestion or idea..not a coded solution .thanks :)

[image]

problem is in the red circled area user will put their comment and click post button.it will be uploaded to the database by an ajax call using firendComment.php page. But cant update the post by showing this comment uploaded?how can i do that.For convenience i am supplying my entire script here:

```
<?php
      session_start();
      require_once 'myDB.php';
      if(isset($_POST['post']) && !empty($_POST['post'])){
           $post=$_POST['post'];
           $_SESSION['post']=$_POST['post'];

           try{
               $newComment=DB::getInstance();
               $newComment->insert('post',array('posts'=>$post));
              }catch(Exception $e){
                 echo $e->getMessage();
              }
           header('HTTP/1.1 303 see other');
           header('Location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
        }    
?>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    #formdiv{width:347px;height:120px;background:#dfe3ee;position:relative;border:1px dashed black;top:0px;left:300px;padding:5px; margin-bottom:3px;

    }
    #individual{background:#f7f9f7;display:block;height:30px;padding:6px;}
    #cmntbox{
        width:347px;background:#dfe3ee;position:relative;border:1px solid black;left:300px;padding:5px;margin-bottom:10px;
    }
    .repText{
        width:100%;background:#f7f7f7;position:relative;border:1px solid black;padding:3px;resize:none;}
    }
</style>
</head>
</body>
<div id='formdiv'>
    <form action='' method='POST'>
        <textarea name='post' placeholder="what's on your mind !" cols='40' rows='3'></textarea>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='post comment' style='float:right;width:100px;height:30px;background:#3b5998;color:white;'>
    </form>
</div>
<?php 

      $newComment=DB::getInstance();
      $results=$newComment->getComment('SELECT','post',array('posts','id'))->result();


      foreach($results as $result=>$val){
      $postid='rep'.$val->id;
      $hiddenid='hidden'.$val->id;
?>        
    <div  id='cmntbox'><?php 
         echo $val->posts;
         echo '</br><hr>';
         $comments=$newComment->get('cmnt',array('postid','=',$val->id))->result();
         foreach($comments as $comment){
         ?>
         <div id='individual'><?php echo $comment->cmnts; ?></div>
         <hr>
         <?php 
           }
         ?>
         <form action='friendComment.php' method='post'>
             <textarea name='myrep' id='<?php echo $postid; ?>' class='repText'></textarea>
             <input type='button' class='reply' value='reply' style='width:50px;height:30px;background:#3b5998;color:white;' >
             <input type='hidden' id='<?php echo $hiddenid; ?>' class='hiddenfield' name='postid' value='<?php echo $val->id; ?>'>
        </form>
    </div>
<?php 
    }

?>
<script>
   var reply=document.getElementsByClassName('reply');
   var repText=document.getElementsByClassName('repText');
   var hidden=document.getElementsByClassName('hiddenfield');
   for(i=0;i<reply.length;i++){
       (function(i){
            reply[i].addEventListener('click',function(e){

                  var xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                      if(xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200){
                           console.log(xmlHttp.responseText);//do nothing
                      }

                  }  
                  var parameters='myrep='+repText[i].value+'&postid='+hidden[i].value;
                  xmlHttp.open("POST", "friendComment.php", true);

                  xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                  xmlHttp.send(parameters);
                  });
            })(i);
       }


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

friendComment.php page :

```
session_start();
require_once 'myDB.php';
if(isset($_POST['myrep']) && isset($_POST['postid'])){
   if(!empty($_POST['myrep']) && !empty($_POST['postid'])){
     // echo $_POST['postid'].' has a comment of '.$_POST['myrep'];
     $getDB=DB::getInstance();
     $getDB->insert('cmnt',array('postid'=>$_POST['postid'],'cmnts'=>$_POST['myrep']));
     $results=$getDB->getComment('SELECT','cmnt',array('postid','cmnts'));
     print_r($results);

   }
}
```

Comment: just append comment on div... it will be automatically last

Comment: Why are you going thru all these hassles, build it with JS Framework such as Angular or Reaact

Comment: You don't have to select the comment after insertion. Just [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) the inserted comment in `DOM`.

Comment: @NullPoiиteя you mean by javascript inside the ajax function ?

Comment: @HarshalCarpenter  not familiar with those frameworks..besides it's helping me to understand the language better ..thanks for your advice..will look forward to learn those frameworks :)

Comment: @RayonDabre  do you also mean to update the dom using javascript ? i thought retrieveing it from database would be better

Comment: @HarshalCarpenter before knowing core things properly using framework is just a bad idea, its better to know what is happening behind the screen

Comment: may be it can help you  http://www.9lessons.info/2011/09/submit-form-without-refreshing-page.html

Comment: As was already said, you can just append comment locally with javascript. If you need response from the server, you can for example change Ajax request from `POST` to `GET` and make server (php code) send you response when comment is successfully inserted to database. If you want to see comments from other users, you either have to periodically check with Ajax, if other comments were added to database, or use websockets for two way communication (update all clients when new comment was added), but I think this would be overkill for this case.

Comment: like Rayon telling what you need to do is make ajax request return whether comment submit process to db is success or not .. and on success append it to dom via js ( and you already have the message

Comment: @web2tips  no jquary please !!

Comment: on ajax response append to the innerHTML of div of id `cmntbox` with textbox with `id='<?php echo $postid; ?>'`  it will look like this  
`<div id='individual'>textbox content </div>`  inorder to do without refresh you have to update dom with javascript no other way.

Comment: beside appending it to dom with JS  , can i use a sitInterval function within which there will be a function which will execute an ajax call so that i can keep track of  whether the database was updated or not then if updated i can retrieve the comments ?